# Call cloud function from angular app with parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have Angular + Firebase application.

In my Cloud Functions I have next func:

```
export const getUserByEmail = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const email = request.body.email

  admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
    .then(user => {
      response.send(user)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      response.status(500).send(error)
    })
})
```

And in Angular Service I want to call it:

```
  getUserByEmail(email) {
    const getUserData = this.fireFunction.httpsCallable('getUserByEmail')

    return getUserData({ request.body.email: email })
  }
```

Is it correct way, how it's work? Or how should I call function with parameters?

Comment: Change the request body passed in getUserData({....}) to {body: {email: "email@email.co"}} that should be the right way

Comment: @HimanshuChaudhary cloud function did not see body in request at all, when I `console.log(request.body)` it's log 'undefined'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually mixing up [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0) and [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

You Cloud Function code corresponds to an HTTP one (`functions.https.onRequest(...)`) but the code in your front-end calls a Callable one (`const getUserData = this.fireFunction.httpsCallable('getUserByEmail')`).

You should adapt one or the other, most probably adapt your Cloud Function to a Callable one, along the following lines:

```
exports.getUserByEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const email = data.email;

  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email )
  .then(userRecord => {
        const userData = userRecord.toJSON();
        return { userData: userData };
  })
});
```

Comment: what about function body that also needs to be sent along with that call? How would you send it?

Comment: @ahsannissar Have a look at the documentation on how to call a Callable Cloud Function from a client: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function